# Angularjs + RESTful API exposed registration

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, authorization, token

We started developing a RESTful app for registrations, signing in and posting some simple stuff. We're using AngularJS for the frontend which handles users registering, logging in, signing out etc.

The backend accepts the following paths:

`POST /register` (params: email, password)
`POST /login` (params: email, password)
`POST /logout`

After the user logs in, a JSON token is generated. This token is then used for each and every subsequent request - like `GET /items` or `DELETE /items/5`. Without that token every request is denied with a 401. This part works perfectly because I can use the API in a browser through AngularJS, in an iPhone/Android App and even for 3rd parties.

The only publicly exposed paths are `/register` and `/login`. While doing a POST on `/login` from the outside is natural and makes sense I'm worried that anyone can do a `POST /register` from the outside and just flood the server with registrations.

I found somebody doing a similar app, I just launched POSTMAN and did a POST query on `/signup` which worked.
http://www.mircozeiss.com/github-like-signup-form-with-angularjs-and-bootstrap-v3/

I can't help but think that this is not a best practice scenario when it comes to registering users. Registering users with Google+ or Facebook is not an optimal solution. Any ideas on how to prevent bogus/flood registrations from outside? Is there a way to secure this part of the API (`/register`)? Should I just rate limit the number of requests?

Comment: I just found your question and I am facing the same issue. What's your final solution ?

Comment: we decided to just rate limit certain paths (like `/login`) using rack-attack. Furthermore we disabled CORS for those queries and added a check for the origin and referrer headers. Rack-attack also has a pretty useful fail2ban-like feature so you can ban misbehaving clients.

Comment: and regarding registration: we require a valid email and email activation. So if somebody registers 5 times he'll get banned and the unactivated accounts will be automatically cleaned up after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

If it's free for all app, better X-Rate-Limit the register api endpoint like Github and all, otherwise just process register requests if it has a auth token with admin privileges (allowed to create credentials for other app-user).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we've looked into implementing some rate limiting techniques such as mod_security, rack-attack, iptables, netfilter. Seems we have to do this anyways, no matter if the register page uses a REST API or is just a normal page.

Answer (score 1):

> The backend accepts the following paths:
>
> - POST /register (params: email, password)
> - POST /login (params: email,
>     password)
> - POST /logout

First of all, this is not a REST API, because it violates the [stateless constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) of REST. Use encrypted connection and send the username and password in the HTTP basic auth header with every request. That is stateless.

> Any ideas on how to prevent bogus/flood registrations from outside? Is
>   there a way to secure this part of the API (/register)? Should I just
>   rate limit the number of requests?

This does not depend on REST. You can do just the same with every web application which allows registration. Typical solutions to use a captcha or send a verification link in email. You can limit the rate, but that is not an effective solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While I'm aware that REST APIs should be stateless using Basic HTTP Auth is not always practical (e.g. when using browsers). A lot of people are moving towards tokens which require previous authentication (OAuth, JSON Web Tokens). This way the user ID is always encrypted in the Token itself.
We've already implemented e-mail verification but CAPTCHA doesn't seem to be so easy to implement with angularjs.

Comment: Using tokens is a bad practice I think. Check if the token count increases by the client count. If yes, then it will scale badly. However by small or medium size system this price can be acceptable.

Comment: There are [captcha modules](http://ngmodules.org/tags/captcha) by angular, but I don't have much expertise with that system...